# CSS background gradient repeating on overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm using a gradient as a background and it stretches out as far as the end of the page however after scrolling/overflow it starts to repeat. How can I stretch the gradient out to the bottom of the page even after scrolling?

```
    html
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

background: rgb(242,245,246); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%, rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%, rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(242,245,246,1)), color-stop(37%,rgba(227,234,237,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(200,215,220,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f5f6', endColorstr='#c8d7dc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you have miss-ordered some of your CSS properties. Take a look at this section.

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background: rgb(242,245,246); /* Old browsers */
```

You have specified the long-hand properties `background-repeat` and `background-attachment`, before the short-hand `background` property. When the `background` property is read, it will reset all the previously set background properties.

Just move them beneath your other background properties, and it will work.

```css
html
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background: rgb(242,245,246); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%, rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%, rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(242,245,246,1)), color-stop(37%,rgba(227,234,237,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(200,215,220,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f5f6', endColorstr='#c8d7dc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
<h1>blah</h1>
```

Comment: Well spotted.  This is the best answer.

Comment: Good answer!. Also, you could use **background-image** instead of *background*; then the order is irrelevant..

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `height:100%` from `html`:

```css
html
{
   
    width:100%;
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

background: rgb(242,245,246); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%, rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%, rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(242,245,246,1)), color-stop(37%,rgba(227,234,237,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(200,215,220,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f5f6', endColorstr='#c8d7dc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  <p>blah</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in a separete `body` call after your actual `body` :

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

your css needs to be like this :

```
    html
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;



background: rgb(242,245,246); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%, rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%, rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(242,245,246,1)), color-stop(37%,rgba(227,234,237,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(200,215,220,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f5f6', endColorstr='#c8d7dc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

body {
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

**for order reason**

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ecKR4/96/)**

Comment: no need to have separate `body` selector block; you can place the `background-attachment` and `background-repeat` entries after the `filter` line.

Comment: i know that but this solution is already in the previews answer so here is another :) and both of them works well ,

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way, add blank div and attach this CSS to it ( http://jsbin.com/jugiyutibu/1/edit)

```
.bg
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:-1;
background: rgb(242,245,246); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%, rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%, rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(242,245,246,1)), color-stop(37%,rgba(227,234,237,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(200,215,220,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,245,246,1) 0%,rgba(227,234,237,1) 37%,rgba(200,215,220,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f5f6', endColorstr='#c8d7dc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```